# Creating a firebase storage reference from a "gs" url in string format

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have stored a firebase `StorageReference` inside of Firebase Database by converting the reference itself into a string , and I get the error below when trying to use the ".getInstance" method to recreate the reference from its string version.

The error:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri cannot contain a path element.`

The storage reference itself(that got converted into a string): `val personalstorageref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("${auth.currentUser!!.email}/Posts/${filename}")`

the storage reference string version inside of database:`gs://stnok-25330.appspot.com/hell%20gmail.com/Posts/d1dad470-25ad-3ffb-q422-22cca5e5596o`

The way I tried to create the storage reference from the gs path :`var refurl = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(listset.refslist[i]!!).reference`

few things to note about the way i attempted to create the storage reference from the gs path: The object `listset` contains a mutablelist of gs paths which is `refslist`, `i` is  a Int.

I have seen similar questions to mine , but none fit my usecase.

**Edit:**
I tried to use the getReferencefromurl method , which returns the error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.

The url inside of the database exists 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirebaseStorage.getInstance(String)` is used for constructing a FirebaseStorage object instance for the bucket given as the argument.  The error message is telling you that the gs URL can not have a path component (only a bucket name).  It's not for converting a gs file paths.

Instead you will probably just want to:

1. Get a normal FirebaseStorage instance using `getInstance()` with no parameters.
2. Call [storage.getReferenceFromUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)) and pass the full gs URL to get a StorageRefence that points to that file

Comment: In case anyone stumbled upon this question from javascript land, for some reason the function name is different. It will be `storage.refFromURL()` instead.